# git pre-commit : the file is modified AFTER the commit

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook

So, i want to add a time of commit within a specific file IF was modified. The problem is that the file is modified AFTER the commit not before the commit, with the obvious conclusion that pre-commit hook is run after the commit. What do i miss? how can i run a hook before the act of commiting?
Thanks!

Comment: Food for thought: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55583651/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/a/12802592/7976758

Comment: thanks a lot for both explanation and solution (second link) :)